# scikit-learn pipeline: grid search over parameters of transformer to generate data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I would like to use the first step of a scikit-learn pipeline to generate a toy data set in order to evaluate the performance of my analysis. An as-simple-as-it-gets-example solution I came up with looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn import cluster

class FeatureGenerator(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, num_features=None):
        self.num_features = num_features

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        return np.array(
            range(self.num_features*self.num_features)
        ).reshape(self.num_features,
                  self.num_features)

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {"num_features": self.num_features}

    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        self.num_features = parameters["num_features"]
        return self
```

This transformer in action would e. g. be called like this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('pick_features', FeatureGenerator(100)),
    ('kmeans', cluster.KMeans())
])

pipeline = pipeline.fit(None)
classes = pipeline.predict(None)
print classes
```

It gets tricky for me as soon as I try to grid search over this pipeline:

```
parameter_sets = {
    'pick_features__num_features' : [10,20,30],
    'kmeans__n_clusters' : [2,3,4]
}

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('pick_features', FeatureGenerator()),
    ('kmeans', cluster.KMeans())
])

g_search_estimator = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameter_sets)

g_search_estimator.fit(None,None)
```

The grid search expects the samples and the labels as input and is not as robust as the pipeline, which does not complain about `None` as input parameter:

```
TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <type 'NoneType'>
```

This makes sense, because the grid search needs to divide the data set in to different cv-partitions.

---

Other than in the above example, I have a lot of parameters, that can be adjusted in the data set generation step. I thus need a solution to include this step into my parameter selection cross-validation.

**Question:** Is there a way to set the `X`s and `y`s of the GridSearch from inside the first transformer? Or how could a solution look like, that calls the GridSearch with multiple different data sets (preferably parallel)? Or has anyone tried to customize `GridSearchCV` or can point to some reading materials on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very clean so it is a pleasure to offer you this quick and dirty solution:

```
g_search_estimator.fit([1., 1., 1.],[1., 0., 0.])
g_search_estimator.best_params_
```

Output:

```
[tons of int64 to float64 conversion warnings]
{'kmeans__n_clusters': 4, 'pick_features__num_features': 10}
```

Note you need 3 samples because you're doing a (default) 3-fold cross validation.

The error you get happens because of a check performed by the `GridSearchCV` object so it happens before your transformer has a chance of doing anything. So I would say "no" to your first question:

> Is there a way to set the Xs and ys of the GridSearch from inside the
>   first transformer?

**EDIT:**
I realize this was unnecessarily confusing, the three following lines are equivalent:
g_search_estimator.fit([1., 1., 1.], [1., 0., 0.])
g_search_estimator.fit([1., 1., 1.], None)
g_search_estimator.fit([1., 1., 1.])

Sorry for hastily throwing random `y`s in there.

Some explanations about how the grid search computes scores for the different grid points: when you pass `scoring=None` to the `GridSearchCV` constructor (this is the default so that's what you have here), it asks the estimator for a score function. If there is such a function it is used for scoring. For `KMeans` the default score function is essentially the opposite of the sum of distances to cluster centers.
This is an unsupervised metrics so `y` is not necessary here.

Wrapping it up, you will always be able to:

> set the Xs of the GridSearch from inside the first transformer

Just 'transform' the input `X` into something totally unrelated, no one will complain about it. You do need *some* input `random_X` though.
Now if you want to use supervised metrics (I have this feeling from your question) you'll need to specify `y` as well.
An easy scenario is one where you have a fixed `y` vector and you want to try several `X` with that. Then you can just do:

```
g_search_estimator.fit(random_X, y, scoring=my_scoring_function)
```

and it should run fine. If you want to search over different values of `y` it will probably be a bit trickier.

Comment: doesn't this use the `y`s you pass in to score the solution?

Comment: No, when you pass scoring=None (default) to `GridSearchCV`, it uses the score function of the estimator if there is such a function. If you try specifying a scoring function with this `y` you'll get an error in its execution. For `KMeans` there is a 'default' score function, so it is this one that is used. See `km = KMeans()` then the `km.score` method. It is an unsupervised metrics, essentially (minus) the sum of distances to cluster centers. Do you want to use supervised metrics? If so please add some details to your question.